# Could not autowire field @Autowired Annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, autowired

I am using Spring version 3 and hibernate version 4 with jdk 1.7.
I can't solved error of could not autowired field.

**Login.java**

```
package com.tanmay.model;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@NamedQueries(  
        {  
            @NamedQuery(  
            name = "validateUserQuery",  
            query = "from Login l where l.userName =:userName AND l.userPassword =:userPassword" 
            )  
        }  
    )  

@Entity
@Table(name="login")
public class Login {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    private String userName;

    @Basic
    private String password;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**LoginAPIController.java**

```
package com.tanmay.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.tanmay.dto.LoginDTO;
import com.tanmay.dto.ResponseDTO;
import com.tanmay.model.Login;
import com.tanmay.service.LoginService;
/**
 * 
 * @author TANMAY
 *
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/user")
public class LoginAPIController extends BaseController{

    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService; 

    /**
     * 
     * @param loginDTO
     * @param request
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody   
    public ResponseDTO login(@RequestBody LoginDTO loginDTO , HttpServletRequest request)throws Exception{

        Login login = new Login();

        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>> userName "+loginDTO.getUsername());
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>> userPassword "+loginDTO.getUserpassword());

        if(loginDTO.getUsername()!=null && loginDTO.getUserpassword()!=null){

            login = loginService.validateUser(loginDTO.getUsername(), loginDTO.getUserpassword());

            if(login!=null){
                return ResponseDTO.ok(login);
            }
            else{
                return ResponseDTO.not_found(-1, "UserName / Password invalid");
            }
        }
        else{
            return ResponseDTO.bad_request("Please Enter UserName or Password");
        }
    }   
}
```

**LoginDaoImpl.java**

```
package com.tanmay.daoimpl;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.tanmay.dao.BaseDao;
import com.tanmay.dao.LoginDao;
import com.tanmay.misc.DESEncryption;
import com.tanmay.model.Login;

@Repository("loginDao")
public class LoginDaoImpl extends BaseDao implements LoginDao {

    @Override
    public Login validateUser(String userName, String userPassword) throws Exception {
        DESEncryption desEncryption = new DESEncryption();
        return (Login) getSession().getNamedQuery("validateUserQuery")
                .setString("userName", userName)
                .setString("userPassword", desEncryption.encrypt(userPassword)).uniqueResult();
    }
}
```

**LoginServiceImpl**

```
package com.tanmay.serviceimpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.tanmay.dao.LoginDao;
import com.tanmay.model.Login;
import com.tanmay.service.LoginService;
@Service("loginService")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class LoginServiceImpl implements LoginService {

    @Autowired
    private LoginDao loginDao;

    @Override
    public Login validateUser(String userName, String userPassword) throws Exception {
        return loginDao.validateUser(userName, userPassword);
    }

}
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tanmay" /> 

     <bean id="apiPropertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:db-config.properties</value>
<!--                   <value>classpath:email-config.properties</value> -->
                    <value>classpath:messages_en.properties</value>
           </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
<!--    <import resource="classpath:email-config.xml"/> -->
     <import resource="classpath:db-config.xml"/> 
    <bean id="configurationLoader"
        class="org.springmodules.validation.bean.conf.loader.annotation.AnnotationBeanValidationConfigurationLoader">
    </bean>    
    <bean id="validator" class="org.springmodules.validation.bean.BeanValidator" >
        <property name="configurationLoader" ref="configurationLoader"></property>
    </bean>

<!--     Message resource declaration -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:/messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/> 
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

**Error / Console Log**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginAPIController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.tanmay.service.LoginService com.tanmay.controller.LoginAPIController.loginService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.tanmay.dao.LoginDao com.tanmay.serviceimpl.LoginServiceImpl.loginDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.tanmay.dao.BaseDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [db-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: validateUserQuery
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:600)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:519)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:460)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3746)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5528)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1378)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1350)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.tanmay.service.LoginService com.tanmay.controller.LoginAPIController.loginService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.tanmay.dao.LoginDao com.tanmay.serviceimpl.LoginServiceImpl.loginDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.tanmay.dao.BaseDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [db-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: validateUserQuery
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.tanmay.dao.LoginDao com.tanmay.serviceimpl.LoginServiceImpl.loginDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.tanmay.dao.BaseDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [db-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: validateUserQuery
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:891)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:834)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.tanmay.dao.LoginDao com.tanmay.serviceimpl.LoginServiceImpl.loginDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.tanmay.dao.BaseDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [db-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: validateUserQuery
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.tanmay.dao.BaseDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [db-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: validateUserQuery
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:891)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:834)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.tanmay.dao.BaseDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [db-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: validateUserQuery
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [db-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: validateUserQuery
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:891)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:834)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 59 more
```

Comment: can you commentout @Service("loginService") ?

Comment: also Show your LoginService  interface

Comment: @georgesvan i commented out it, still problem arise.

Comment: @georgesvan public interface LoginService { public Login validateUser(String userName, String userPassword) throws Exception;
 
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your named query

```
 @NamedQuery(  
        name = "validateUserQuery",  
        query = "from Login l where l.userName =:userName AND l.userPassword =:userPassword" 
        )
```

You are referring to a `l.userPassword` but the field is called `password`. Change `l.userPassword` to `password`.